# PHP 5.5.12 ROUND return always up

Tags: php, rounding

Tested in wamp server with PHP 5.5.12
This return always up

```
echo round(3.51,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);// 4
echo round(3.51,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);// 4
```

Why?

Comment: What do you expect? 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`round()` rounds to the nearest integer. `3.51` is closer to `4` than `3`, so it always rounds to that.

The options you used only affect what happens when the fractional part of the input is exactly `.5`, since that's equally distant from both integers.

If you always want to round down, use `floor()` instead of `round()`. Conversely, if you want to round up, use `ceil()`. Many programming languages use these same names with similar meaning -- they come from basic mathematics.